# how to add delay in the code to be executed, in Java?

Tags: java, delay, depth-first-search, maze

I was trying build a Maze_Generator using DFS. I have implemented the algorithm successfully, but it is not visual (i.e. as soon as I run the program, the complete grid is coloured, but I want to see each box getting coloured in real time).

Below is Draw class, which draws the Grid and colours them, if the box has been marked visited(by algorithm).

```
class Draw extends JPanel{
    
    public Draw() {}

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g1) {
        super.paintComponent(g1);
        Graphics2D g= (Graphics2D) g1;
//Code Below makes the grid
for(Cell c: Maze_Generator.list) {  //Maze_Generator.list, this is ArrayList, storing all the cells/boxes objects
            //Cell c =(Cell)a;
            if(c.top())
                g.drawLine(c.x(), c.y(), c.x()+c.length(), c.y());
            if(c.bottom())
                g.drawLine(c.x(), c.y()+c.length(),c.x()+c.length(),c.y()+c.length());
            if(c.left())
                g.drawLine(c.x(), c.y(), c.x(), c.y()+c.length());
            if(c.right())
                g.drawLine(c.x()+c.length(), c.y(), c.x()+c.length(), c.y()+c.length());
        }
        
//Code below colours the boxes if marked visited
        for(Cell c:Maze_Generator.list) {
            if(c.visited()) {
                g.setColor(Color.cyan);
                g.fillRect(c.x()+1, c.y()+1, c.length()-1, c.length()-1);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
            }
        }
    }



}
```

What and how should I do to slow down/delay the code when colouring the boxes?
Any suggestions?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using sleep in JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247668/using-sleep-in-jpanel)

Comment: You should not use sleep() in the central gui thread. Instead, use another thread as a Timer.

Comment: using sleep, pauses my main thread, and UI does not show up(only white screen). And when using a new thread specifically for Sleep method, code dealing with graphics does not work inside this new Thread(but regular output print code does work tho)

Comment: Look below. Don't use `Thread.sleep(int)`.

Comment: See an example of updating a grid using SwingWorker [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50781879/3992939). It can also be achieved using a Swing Timer as TimonNetherlands suggested. **_"it seemed i was not clear with my question"_** : for more help post [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a timer, otherwise you'll block your main thread.
This should work, but improve it to fit your needs:

```
// add necessary imports first:
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

```
int milliseconds = 500;
for(Cell c:Maze_Generator.list) {
    if(c.visited()) {
        fillRect(milliseconds, g, c.x()+1, c.y()+1, c.length()-1, c.length()-1);
        milliseconds += 500;
    }
}
```

Add this method:

```
    private void fillRect( int delay, Graphics2D g, int x, int y, int width, int height ) {
        Timer timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                g.setColor(Color.cyan);
                g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats( false );
        timer.start();
    }
```

Comment: it seems like its not working for me..
No delay, everything show up at runtime.

Comment: Are the lines drawn immediately? Or are they invisible (same color as background)? I didn't apply the timer to the colors, because it'd work in the same way.

Comment: lines are invisible actually, the squares are drawn because of my previous code. And when I replace my code with yours, i get a white screen

Comment: Edited the response to delay drawing of colors instead of delaying grid drawing,

Comment: thanks for the help buddy, but I managed to pull it off in an other way....